# $exception->getTraceAsString() first item missing

Tags: php

I throw an exception inside à `file.php` I want to catch and display the trace for debugging, but the trace is incomplete when I get it with `$exception->getTraceAsString()`. The trace is correct when I use `debug_print_backtrace()` inside the exception constructor:

```php
# page.php, called by index.php
<?php
class CustomException extends Exception {
    public function __construct($message = "", $code = 0, $previous = null) {
        echo '<pre>';
        debug_print_backtrace();
        echo '</pre>';
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
}

try {
    include('file.php'); // throw a CustomException
} catch (CustomException $e) {
    echo '<pre>' . $e->getTraceAsString() . '</pre>';
    echo '<hr>';
    echo '</pre>';

}

# output of debug_print_backtrace():
#0  App\Exception… called at [/path/to/file.php:1396]
#1  include(/path/to/file.php) called at [/path/to/page.php:3]
#2  require_once(/path/to/page.php) called at [/path/to/index.php:100]

# output of $e->getTraceAsString():
#0 /path/to/page.php(3): include()
#1 /path/to/index.php(100): require_once('/path/to/i...')
#2 {main}
```

Is there a way to get the full `traceAsString` (and more important for me, the output of `$e->getTrace()`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTrace()`/`getTraceAsString()` seems to be just the trace, but not the error message. You can always build your own line, which can also help with readability. I use something like this on a lot of my logging, which is useful even when I don't include the trace:

```
$error_string = "Error with (whatever it is), ".$e->getMessage() . " on " . $e->getLine() . " of " . $e->getFile();
```

You can also check to see what kind of exception it might be:

```
$error_string .= " - Exception of type ".get_class($e);
```

Comment: This is the right answer (I found it right after asking the question -_- ). All info related to the error are in the exception objet itself, the trace is everything else. Thanks you anyway :)